# Chaining JSON Paths in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am exposing JSONPaths for advanced queries in my application, and sometimes it would be really convenient to chain expressions as I'd do for example with `jq`. Example:

```json
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "bar",
      "from": 10,
      "to": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$.foo[*] ? (@.bar == "bar") | @.to - @.from
```

Now I see that the `|` operator as used above is not implemented, and in pure SQL I could store the result of the first part in a table / variable. However in application I pass the JSONPath to `jsonb_path_query` and it would be convenient if I didn't have to chain the invocations manually but just let PostgreSQL handle it all in one pre-baked statement. Is there anything that would let me do that?

**EDIT**: I could do that using e.g.

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query((
   SELECT jsonb_path_query('{ ... }', '$.foo[*] ? (@.bar == "bar")')
), '$.to - $.from');
```

but that would mean that I'd need to split the JSONPath query (user input) - exactly what I don't want to do in the app.

Comment: What do you mean by "*in pure SQL I could store the result of the first part in a table / variable.*"?

Comment: So the question is if I understand well: is it possible to write the above `jq` query using SQL ?

Comment: @zakariaamine Not really. Full `jq` syntax aside, the question is whether it is possible to do it within single instance of `jsonpath` type, so that I can pass the param to `jsonb_path_query` function.

Comment: @RadimVansa "*the question is whether it is possible to do it within single instance of `jsonpath` type*" - I guess you already answered that yourself in the question, stating that `|` is not implemented? Or are you looking for a different way of writing this particular example, i.e. `$.foo[*]?(@.bar=="bar").to - $.foo[*]?(@.bar=="bar").from`?

Comment: @Bergi That would work since this example selects single numeric value, but had there be more matching items, the `-` wouldn't work as vector operation. And I would be concerned if Postgres smart enough to not perform the lookup twice.

Comment: Yes, I tend to know answer for what I am exactly asking but there might be some way around it, or syntax I just didn't get from the few examples in documentation.

Comment: I don't believe there are json path operators that are implemented but not documented. Nesting `jsonb_path_query` calls is exactly the way to go, and sql result sets nicely mirror the streaming semantics of `jq`